# How to run a woocommerce email notification function from inside a custom php script

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to run something similar to this function.

```
wp_new_user_notification( $new_user_id );
```

this function above works already but I would like to use the woocommerce function. As that includes a better email template. I know I can tick it on in the woocommerce admin. But I am using my own form script for the user registration. Which doesn't trigger the woocommerce email notification.

I found this function somewhere in the woocommerce code but I have no idea how to use it.

```
woocommerce_created_customer_notification.
```

Please help thanks!

Comment: Totally unclear question. What you mean by "I would like to use the woocommerce version of it?"

Comment: I would like to use the function that woocommerce uses to mail the customer a notification. woocommerce_created_customer_notification()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right woocommerce includes a better email template, but this is not a good practice to use them in php script for registration script.
You can use your custom code for new user registration email and change you email template as you wish.
For second option there are many plugins available for new user email.
like :https://wordpress.org/plugins/welcome-email-editor/

Comment: I am using the woocommerce emails for other things like orders. So thats why I want to use it. Do you perhaps know how to fire a woocommerce email function outside the functions.php?

Comment: I don't  think you can fire it outside , because this are using some parameters and hooks for initialise, so better way is create you own function for fire email.